# Adding a certain image to a JPanel in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface

So, I want to draw an image based on the current selection of a scroll list in java Swing. It seems the best way to do this is to add an label to a panel. I tried multiple various ways of doing this and for the life of me I can't figure why it won't display the image. This is a snippet of what I have managed to do so far.

```
private void jList1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    

        ImageIcon greenDragon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Ilmari\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\GUI harkkatyö\\src\\Ile\\Green_dragon.png");
        JLabel dragon = new JLabel();
        dragon.setIcon(greenDragon);
        String selectedMonster = jList1.getSelectedValue();

        if(selectedMonster.equals("Green Dragon")){
            jPanel1.add(dragon);
        }
        else if(selectedMonster.equals("Black Demon")){
    }
}
```

The best outcome so far has been overriding the background JLabel image completely and only displaying a white box with the image.

Comment: wheres your repaint method? thats where the image is supposed to be displayed

Comment: I don't have one actually, do I need to call something like JPanel.repaint(); everytime I modify the image?

Comment: if you are programming using a JPanel you should a defined repaint method, that you write yourself

Answer (score 1):

```
JLabel dragon = new JLabel();
```

This label should be declared as an attribute of the class, and added to the GUI when it is first made. Then in the `jList1MouseClicked` method, simply call `dragon.setIcon(..)`.

That way there is no need to revalidate the GUI on each image change.

On the subject of `jList1MouseClicked`: Use the [most optimized listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener-javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener-) for a `JList`. A `ListSelectionListener` will react to keyboard input as well as mouse input, and provides other advantages besides.

Answer (score 0):

If the image isn't displayed at all. You need to revalidate and repaint your frame.

To achieve that - add this to your code:

```
frame.getContentPane().validate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```